# Как получить значения List при вмешательстве других потоков?

Tags: c#

Есть несколько потоков, которые добавляют значения в:

`public static List<TimeSpan> SpisokVremeni { get; set; }`

А есть поток, который хочет перебрать этот список `SpisokVremeni` и скопировать значения в свой локальный список.

Но вот при переборе этого `SpisokVremeni` в `foreach`, возникают проблемы, другие потоки добавляют значения и естественно вылетает исключение.

Как такой момент обойти ? Как получить копию без исключений ?

Пробовал так, но на потоки которые добавляют значения в `SpisokVremeni` - это никак не повлияло:

```
    List<TimeSpan> kopiyaSpiskaVremeni = new();

    lock (locker)
    {
        foreach (TimeSpan vremya in MyClass.SpisokVremeni)
        {
            kopiyaSpiskaVremeni.Add(vremya);
        }
    }

    return kopiyaSpiskaVremeni;
```

Comment: @aepot: Наверное, не совсем дубликат? Здесь автор не просит потокобезопасную коллекцию, а спрашивает, почему проблемы возникают несмотря на `lock`.

Comment: @VladD потому что он обращается к коллекции в сторонних местах не используя этот же лок. Решение - потокобезопасная коллекция, которая обеспечивает целостность данных при работе из нескольких потоков одновременно. Использование одного лока в 100500 местах кода - это хоть и решение, но костыль.

Comment: @VladD к тому же использование мониторов `lock` для операций чтения/записи в коллекцию - мягко говоря, не очень хорошее решение, так как при работе с коллекцией лучше реализовать R/W Lock или использовать элементы синхронизации дотнета, уже реализуюзие это.

Comment: @aepot: С потокобезопасными коллекциями есть много проблем. Например, её сложно реализовать «правильно», т. к. разный код имеет разное представление о том, что именно нужно защищать и как именно будет использоваться код (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe). Во-вторых, такое решение не является composable (как бы это сказать по-русски?): если вам нужно защитить комбинацию из _двух_ коллекций, что будем делать?

Comment: @VladD ну транзации - это уже другая, отдельная история. Как я понял, в вопросе речь не про транзакции. В любом случае лочить между собой операции чтения, когда нет операций записи - странное занятие. Если настаиваете - я переоткрою, мне не принципиально.

Comment: @aepot: Я вроде не говорил о транзакциях? Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @VladD когда нужно обеспечить атомарность операции при модификации нескольких коллекций одновременно - это транзакция.

Comment: @aepot: Ну не две коллекции, а хотя бы просто две int-переменные — это тоже транзакция? Мне подобное нужно чуть ли не везде. Никакой volatile не спасает, т. к. он охраняет только одну переменную. thread-safe collection — это аналог volatile: защищает только эту коллекцию и ничего более.

Comment: @aepot: Я подумал над вашими словами насчёт транзакций. Мне кажется, транзакции всё же сложнее, т. к. они должны бы подразумевать ещё и откат в случае неудачи.

Comment: @VladD все верно, вы меняете 2 коллекции атомарно (у вас же есть для этого причина?), под зонтом из локов, и получаете исключение при изменении второй из двух, какие ваши действия? Я вопрос переоткрыл, если что.

Comment: @aepot: Никаких: ни потокобезопасные коллекции, ни `lock` не обеспечивают сами по себе возможность отката. Для возможности отката пригодились бы immutable-коллекции, хранимые в immutable-объекте, при этом замена старого объекта на новый будет, очевидно, последней операцией.

Comment: @VladD уже говорим о разном, предлагаю забыть, чтобы не скатиться во флуд.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синхронизация — это кооперативная задача. Все, кто работают с разделяемыми данными, должны придерживаться протокола общения.

В простом случае это означает, что блокировку должен брать как читающий код на время чтения, так и записывающий код на время записи. Иначе смысла в блокировке нет никакого.

---

Старайтесь делать под блокировкой как можно меньше. Например, если вам нужно добыть данные из какого-то другого источника (например, из сети или из файла), и записать добытые данные в список, добывайте данные без блокировки, а блокировку берите только на время записи.

---

Кстати, ваш код можно упростить до такого:

```
lock (locker)
    return MyClass.SpisokVremeni.ToList();
```

Но, как вы уже сами выяснили, вам нужно использовать блокировку (тем же объектом `locker`!) и там, где происходит запись.

Comment: а второй и третий абзац не противоречат друг другу? В одном говорится, что блокировать надо и чтение и запись, в другом, что блокировку на время записи только

Comment: @Grundy: третий абзац говорит, что блокировку не нужно распространять на время получения данных для записи из какого-то другого источника. Уточню это.

Comment: Да, так лучше звучит, в первом варианте казалось что речь про один список

Comment: @VladD правильно ли я понял ? Я должен одним и тем же `locker` заблокировать участок  копирования и участок записи. - Верно ? Запись я никак не блокировал xD

Comment: @Алексей верно.

Comment: @aepot - Логично, Спасибо!